# Converting flat dataframe to a nested column schema in pyspark using withField()

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

Fairly new to python, and brand new to pyspark, so please tell me if my question makes no sense.

I'm essentially trying to understand the limitations of using `withField` updates when compared with `struct` for managing nested columns within a dataframe. I took [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65180527/how-to-update-a-value-in-the-nested-column-of-struct-using-pyspark) as a good starting point to articulate my confusion. Essentially it takes a flat source dataset and schema, and looks to convert to a target nested schema.
DBR 14.0
Apache Spark 3.5.0
Python 3.10.12

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# An example data set
sourceDF = [
  ('Jon','','Smith','1580-01-06','M',3000)
]

# the flat structure of the source
sourceSchema = StructType([
    StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
    StructField('middlename', StringType(), True),
    StructField('lastname', StringType(), True),
    StructField('dob', StringType(), True),
    StructField('gender', StringType(), True),
    StructField('score', IntegerType(), True)
])

# the desired nested structure
targetSchema = StructType([
        StructField('name', StructType([
             StructField('title', StringType(), True),
             StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
             StructField('middlename', StringType(), True),
             StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)
             ])),
         StructField('dob', StringType(), True),
         StructField('gender', StringType(), True),
         StructField('score', IntegerType(), True)
         ])

# create the flat source dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = sourceDF, schema = sourceSchema)
for i in targetSchema.fields: # loop through target schema
    if i.name == "name": # identify a nested column (hard-code as "name" for simplicity)
        if "name" not in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumn("name", F.lit(None).cast(i.dataType)) # add struct column to df
            df.printSchema() # shows the successful addition of the nested column

        df = df.withColumn("name", F.col("name").withField("firstname", F.lit("Pete")))
        df = df.withColumn("name", F.col("name").withField("lastname", F.lit("Gordon")))

df.show()
```

I can see the successful creation of the nested column in the df schema, but the attempt to update the data using `withField` returns a Null result (the intention would be to use col rather than lit here, but I wanted to rule out any confusion between the top-level "firstname" and the nested "firstname"):

```
root
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = false)

+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+-----+----+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|       dob|gender|score|name|
+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+-----+----+
|      Jon|          |   Smith|1580-01-06|     M| 3000|NULL|
+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+-----+----+
```

I can use struct, e.g. `df = df.withColumn("name", F.struct("firstname"))`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77346685/pyspark-convert-a-flat-dataframe-to-struct-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75815843/is-there-any-way-to-convert-flatten-dataframe-to-nested-dataframe-using-pyspark), but I'm struggling to see why the `withField` route doesn't work, despite me having successfully created the nested columns in the df schema (the struct route also weirdly alters the nullability of the nested columns, but that's another issue).

If I add the above struct command as follows:

```
if "name" not in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumn("name", F.lit(None).cast(i.dataType)) # add struct column to df
            df.printSchema() # shows the successful addition of the nested column
        df = df.withColumn("name", F.struct("firstname"))
        df = df.withColumn("name", F.col("name").withField("firstname", F.lit("Pete")))
        df = df.withColumn("name", F.col("name").withField("lastname", F.lit("Gordon")))
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

You can see the desired name column (now non-nullable), minus the "title" and "middlename" fields:

```
root
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = false)

+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+-----+--------------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|       dob|gender|score|          name|
+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+-----+--------------+
|      Jon|          |   Smith|1580-01-06|     M| 3000|{Pete, Gordon}|
+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+-----+--------------+
```

Comment: which databricks are you using aws,azure or community.